# Is there any jquery plugin to generate a tip image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The tip text which highlighted in below image serves wells for giving some instruction to first time user. And I notice such pattern several times in different web apps, I guess there must be some javascript libraries to help generating such tip visualize? But I just fail to find the correct keywords to capture them. Any one give some suggestions please?

[1]: http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6071/6031668602_9c7fcf70be_m.jpg ""

------------------updated----------------

Thx for the suggestions for recommending jquery tooltip plugins.

But other than tooltip widgets, what this questions requests is a more specified “tip plugin” which could be used to generate a transparent tip image which contains simply some words in casual font and an arrow points to parent context. Yes, this is a tooltip but not a ordinary tooltip which comes in the form of a box or bubble. 
Traditional tooltip are useful for displaying detail info on the fly, while the tip I mean here performs better to **attract attentions to user for providing some quick tutorial instructions without adding too much visual noises****

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: http://codylindley.com/blogstuff/js/jtip/

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is great for tooltips in jQuery: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

[Demos are available here.](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/)

Comment: Also, the search term you probably wanted was "tooltip" - since that's usually the term for lightweight on-hover popups.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for some sort of tooltip plugin. Here are a few http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-an-user-friendly-tooltip/